# Replacing all dots with a space for all text content outpt inside a PHP ".substr()"

Tags: php, substr

I have a PHP string that looks like this:

```
$text_output .= '<strong>'.substr($k, $pos).'</strong>'."\n";
```

The substr($k, $pos) outputs, for example, a text looking like this:

> Well.this.is.quite.a.long.sentence.considering.all.the.dots.used.here.within.wich.will.break.page.if.it.is.too.long

This means it often make the page non mobile-friendly if the sentence it outputs is very long. Therefore I need to add a piece of code that replaces all dots "." with a space " ". So in the end the output I would want is this:

> Well this is quite a long sentence considering all the dots used here within wich will break page if it is too long

Comment: try `str_replace` function

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
str_replace("."," ",substr($k, $pos));
```

Comment: Thanks @Maninderpreet Singh ! This worked great: Changing **FROM** `.substr($k, $pos).` **TO** `.str_replace("."," ","$k, $pos").`

Comment: a followup question I am trying to place **str_replace** with same result (meaning to replace all dots "." with space " ". How can I add **str_replace** in this query `$read['name']` ?

Comment: do something like this str_replace("."," ",substr($k, $pos)); @panterara

Comment: `str_replace("."," ",$read['name']);` worked great, tried it before but forgot the echo in front of it so nothing was outputed ;)

Comment: mark as right answer;) @panterara